# urllib3 does not open the same article as urllib2 was able to open due to private mode detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

how can I bypass private mode detection with urllib3. I have the following code that does not work:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

articleURL = "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2016/10/18/the-pentagons-massive-new-telescope-is-designed-to-track-space-junk-and-watch-out-for-killer-asteroids/"

import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', articleURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
soup
```

This gives the following error:

```
    </script> <script>var _0x108f=["blockers","pb-adblock-checked","resolve","all","overlay","mobile","desktop","browsers","max","isAnon","isSubscriber","Features","displayOverlay","extListener","getTime","performance","timing","navigationStart","registerPwapiConsumer","getOwnPropertyDescriptor","get","reject","notdetected","standard","notblocked","stack","validate","addEventListener","pb-core-loaded","iterator","symbol","function","constructor","prototype","assign","apply","Keep supporting great journalism by turning off your ad blocker. Or purchase a subscription for unlimited access to real news you can count on.",
'\x3ca data-link-ff\x3d"https://www.washingtonpost.com/steps-for-disabling-firefoxs-native-adblocker/2018/05/21/fb95bf4e-5d37-11e8-b2b8-08a538d9dbd6_story.html" data-link\x3d"https://www.washingtonpost.com/steps-for-disabling-adblocker/2016/09/14/a8c3d4d2-7aac-11e6-bd86-b7bbd53d2b5d_story.html" href\x3d"https://www.washingtonpost.com/steps-for-disabling-adblocker/2016/09/14/a8c3d4d2-7aac-11e6-bd86-b7bbd53d2b5d_story.html"\x3eUnblock ads\x3c/a\x3e','\x3ca href\x3d"https://subscribe.washingtonpost.com/acq/?promo\x3do12" target\x3d"_blank"\x3e\x3cspan class\x3d"subscribe-link"\x3eTry 1 month for $1\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/a\x3e',
"event 86","We noticed you\u2019re browsing in private mode.","Private browsing is permitted exclusively for our subscribers. Turn off private browsing to keep reading this story, or subscribe to use this feature, plus get unlimited digital access.",'\x3ca data-link-ff\x3d"https://helpcenter.washingtonpost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028029392l" data-link\x3d"https://helpcenter.washingtonpost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028029392" href\x3d"https://helpcenter.washingtonpost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028029392"\x3eTurn off private browsing\x3c/a\x3e'
```

It's not my intention to trigger this warning and it works fine with urllib2:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

articleURL = "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2016/10/18/the-pentagons-massive-new-telescope-is-designed-to-track-space-junk-and-watch-out-for-killer-asteroids/"

page = urllib2.urlopen(articleURL).read().decode('utf8','ignore') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
soup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change (you need to specify a `user-agent` header):

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0'}
response = http.request('GET', articleURL, headers=headers)
```